# Button Onclick to hover a div from right to left does not work on my JSP page.

Tags: jquery, css, jsp

Here is my jsp code.. I dont know what i am doing wrong in this code but it is not working at all ..... have no clue where i am going wrong ... can some one help me with this please .

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/feedback.css" type="text/css" media="all">
        <script>
            $("#myButton").click(function () {

    var effect = 'slide'; 
    var options = { direction: 'right' };
    var duration = 700;

    $('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
        </script>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">




    <p>
        <button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
    </p>
    <div id="myDiv">       
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my CSS

```
 body {
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}

 #myButton {
    padding: .2em 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
#myDiv {
    color:Green;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:2px solid #333;
    display:none;
    text-align:justify;
}
#myDiv p {
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 0.917em;
}

 #body {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 534px;
}
html, body {
    background-color:White;
}
```

I think I have given every thing correct but still it does not work can any one help ....

Comment: you missed to add jquery

Comment: I included the jquery library too and it still does not work ..... is this not possible on a jsp page....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the jquery-ui script file into your code

Just wrap the button click code with document [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

//This is added for the toogle method

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font: 12px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
        }

        #myButton {
            padding: .2em 1em;
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        #myDiv {
            color: Green;
            background-color: #eee;
            border: 2px solid #333;
            display: none;
            text-align: justify;
        }

            #myDiv p {
                margin: 15px;
                font-size: 0.917em;
            }

        #body {
            clear: both;
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 534px;
        }

        html, body {
            background-color: White;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">



        $(document).ready(function () {
          // here i put the button click inside the document ready function

            $("#myButton").click(function () {

                var effect = 'slide';
                var options = { direction: 'right' };
                var duration = 700;

                $('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="body">
    <p>
        <button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
    </p>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested this code with chrome it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jquery library  like this

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

or download and add it like this

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I included the jquery library too and it still does not work ..... is this not possible on a jsp page....?

Comment: @Satya thank you for helping me out ...i got it ... i had to include another jquery lib as Sindhu said .... (also the document ready):))

Answer (score 0):

did you include "jquery.js" in your page?
add this to your haed before "script" tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```